# ExpressJS can't serve static files over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, express, https

I'm having a strange problem. Recently I added an HTTPS server to my expressjs application, which runs perfectly fine for the most part. The exception is that certain images retrieved from a folder outside the application (static data, in a folder called '/data' on the same level as app.js) no longer display across the site, whereas they did and still do so fine over on the HTTP server.

I'm including the /data folder using the line below in app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(_dirname, 'data')));
```

These images are thumbnails loaded through css background-image on a div. What's peculiar is that on the HTTPS server, I can still access the image by visiting its URL directly (through the console or address bar), even if the thumbnail is mysteriously missing. The URL is preceded properly with https:// so it's the correct server.

In the console, I'm getting a status code of 307 Internal Redirect, and next to Non-Authoritative Reason underneath Response Headers it says "Delegate". In actuality if I clicked the Preview or Response tabs (this is all in Chrome, by the way) it says "Failed to load response data". What could the problem be?

UPDATE: I tried changing the port for HTTPS to 3000, just for testing purposes. To my surprise the images from the /data folder loaded and displayed just fine. So the issue isn't with HTTPS, but with the port it seems... but I still don't know why.

So to summarize the results so far:

- running on port 80, 443: images don't display
- running on port 1023, 1024, 3000: images display

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Is `_dirname` a typo? It should be `__dirname`.

Comment: Can you show some of the CSS that is failing (particularly where it shows the urls)?

Comment: Yes it's a typo. My bad. The original code has a double underscore __. Also the CSS involved within the div element is as follows:
    <div style="background-image: url('/ads/{{image.foldername}}/{{image.filename}}');"> ... </div>

I'm using angularjs so those are variables from the scope. It's not part of the problem though, as I've attempted to use a direct url to the image.

Comment: I did stumble upon this: https://discussion.heroku.com/t/new-folders-and-bash-and-mystic-307/970/2, in which the user seems to have a very similar if not exact problem to mine. There is a response along with two links posted and a theory, but I'm not sure what concrete solution to draw from that for my case.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive testing, I've concluded that this is likely a problem very specific to my own circumstances, rather than it being expressjs. There is nothing unusual about the "data" folder -- in fact, the webapp has no problem accessing files directly within it. This means that expressjs is including the static directory just like it's supposed to.

The *real* issue lies with content from another specific folder within "data". This is the only scenario where the 307 status is returned. In the end, it seems that the port number is still a factor (since certain other ports do work as I stated in my original post), but it's very very odd. If I copied that folder and renamed it, its content can be accessed just fine. That's my solution for now, I suppose, until I can find the real reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue as well and in my case it was the **ad-blocker** which had blocked all my mock billboard and mock mpu ad images (since they're of a specific size) that were being served from express.

Found it after running the same page in Firefox which didn't have an ad-block extension installed.